# Decoupling receiving data and processing data by passing callback and shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

Sorry for my poor English. I want to decouple receiving data and processing data, this is the [demo code](https://godbolt.org/z/sE8f4qWjh):

```
#include<memory>
#include<iostream>
#include<functional>

using message_handler=std::function<void(const std::string&)>;

class Session: public std::enable_shared_from_this<Session>
{
class PacketProc
{
public:
    void SetOnMsgProc(const message_handler &&on_msg_func)
    {
        this->inner_on_msg_func = on_msg_func;
    }

    void ProcRcved(const std::string &str)
    {
        if(inner_on_msg_func)
        {
            inner_on_msg_func(str);
        }
    }

private:
    message_handler inner_on_msg_func; 
};

public:
    ~Session()
    {
        std::cout << "~Session()" << std::endl;
    }

    void Init(void)
    {
        std::weak_ptr<Session> weak=shared_from_this();
        packet_proc.SetOnMsgProc([weak](const std::string & str){
            auto shared = weak.lock();
            if(shared && shared->outter_on_msg_func)
            {
                shared->outter_on_msg_func(str);
            }
        });

        outter_on_msg_func= [](const std::string & str)
        {
            std::cout << "recieved:" << str << std::endl;
        };
    }

    void Proc(void)
    {
        std::string str = read();
        packet_proc.ProcRcved(str);
    }

    std::string read(void)
    {
        return std::string("this is a test");
    }

private:
    PacketProc packet_proc;
    message_handler outter_on_msg_func;
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Session> pSession= std::make_shared<Session>();
    pSession->Init();
    pSession->Proc();
}
```

Any suggestion and advice is welcome.

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code after an answer has been posted. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Sorry, I am new to code review.

Answer (score 2):

The declaration for the class `PacketProc` should be indented, right now the code is hard to read.

```
class Session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Session>
{
    class PacketProc
    {
    public:
        void SetOnMsgProc(const message_handler&& on_msg_func)
        {
            this->inner_on_msg_func = on_msg_func;
        }

        void ProcRcved(const std::string& str)
        {
            if (inner_on_msg_func)
            {
                inner_on_msg_func(str);
            }
        }

    private:
        message_handler inner_on_msg_func;
    };

public:
    ~Session()
    {
        std::cout << "~Session()" << std::endl;
    }

    ...
};
```

If the class `PacketProc` is supposed to be reusable then it should be declared outside the class `Session`, right now it can only be accessed through the `Session` class.

To follow best practices, operators such as `=` should have blank spaces on both sides:

```
using message_handler = std::function<void(const std::string&)>;
```

That would also improve the readability of the code.

Using the `this` pointer really shouldn't be necessary in this code:

```
                void SetOnMsgProc(const message_handler&& on_msg_func)
                {
                    inner_on_msg_func = on_msg_func;
                }
```

Inside a class it generally isn't necessary to use the `this` pointer, it is the default. The only time this isn't true is is if an identifier has 2 possible uses within the same scope of the code, such as if `inner_on_msg_func` was defined as a global in the `Session` class and a local in the `PacketProc` class.

Comment: "Using the this pointer really shouldn't be necessary in this code."? I can't catch up. Could you please explain that in more detail?

Comment: @John The answer is updated.

Comment: The lambda captures a weak pointer (for Session) in Session::SetOnMsgProc(). Do you think it is redundant? Is there any potential problem that I should be aware of?